# Bookmark - hyperref are a couple of pages off

Tags: hyperref, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [hyperref bad references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75415/hyperref-bad-references)

I'm sort of in an impasse, so I was hopping somebody can help me out.

I'm creating a report for an University project. I created the document and everything, and finally an  extra-request was to setup a bookmarking system with page numbers and section numbers included. I looked into the `hyperref` and `bookmark` package, set up everything and... well it's sort of working, however not really.

My problem is that the page references seem to be off with a couple of pages. Like it does not take into account the `abstract` and `title` section... [Here's](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/36896/oszlopcsaladok_GAB9MT.pdf) the document to see it yourself, and [here's the source files](https://github.com/gaborbernat/latex_NoSQL_oszlopcsaladok/blob/master/oszlopcsaladok/src/main.tex).

Any ideas?

Later Edit:
So here's a short snippet that manifests the symptoms:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,openright]{report}

\usepackage[T1]    {fontenc }% Allow accented output charachters
\usepackage[utf8]  {inputenc}% Allow accented input charachters 
\usepackage[magyar]{babel   }% Set document language to use

\usepackage[style=english]{csquotes} 
\usepackage        {hyperref}% - Add links between the doc
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}
\usepackage[numbered,
              open, 
              openlevel=2,
              atend]{bookmark}% - We want numbers

\begin{document}
\hypersetup{pageanchor=false}
\begin{abstract}
A Google.
\end{abstract}
\hypersetup{pageanchor=true}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Oszlopcsaládok}
Amennyiben adatbázisainkat Edgar F. Codd. 

\section{Oszlopba avagy sorba rendezve?}
A sor orientált.

\section{A ,,széles’’ oszlop családok}
A NoSQL \ref{sec:oszlop_relacios} fejezetben. 

\chapter{Összegzés} \label{sec:oszlop_relacios}
A szerkesztő reménye.

\end{document}
```

I've used TexLive 2012 (inside Eclipse with TexLipse). Create the document. All the links point to the first page (after the abstract, so to the ToC). The interesting point here is the `babel` package usage. I use the Hungarian one (`magyar` option). Now change the `magyar` to `english`. Bang, all the links work as expected.

LLE:
So as I was pointed out in the comments the issue and the solution is described here:  [hyperref bad references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75415/hyperref-bad-references)
Using the new `magyar.ldf` solved the problem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: Actually, once you start to navigate through the bookmarks it's quite straight forward the issue. For instance click on the chapter 3 bookmark. It will take you to page 19, while the chapter starts at page 21.

Comment: Quite probably your log file will contains messages about "destination with the same identifier has already been used". Search this site for relevant messages. Or make a minimal example. You should expect other to debug a complete source.

Comment: It seems to be the standard problem in this case: don't divide `\caption{}` and `\label{}`! `\label{}` has to follow `\caption`, for example: `\caption{Adatbázis feltördelése darabkákra}\label{fig:DatabaseShard}`

Comment: Actually the table references work just fine. As for the pagenumbers, you are right, I've had that warnings, however I've used the \hypersetup{pageanchor=false} command to fix it. Now, while I've tried to create the MWE I noticed something: it's the babel package. If I use the english one everything works fine, switch to the magyar (hungarian) and it's gone. So ideas?

Comment: Added the MWE. Any ideas, what's braking the system if I use the hungarian babel?